# Google SEO and _escaped_fragment_ in light of Google's crawling changes

Tags: javascript, seo, web-crawler, googlebot

Google has just completed (I saw the page refresh in front of me right now) JavaScript indexing. Which is cool since I no longer need all my tooling for that. Google will now execute JavaScript - the SEO JavaScript problem is solved. So far - awesome.

However, I have a bunch of pages I created for the old `!#` fragment scheme. These pages have been indexed until now, and I intend to keep serving them for old (IE7-) browsers. The newer SPA pages contain more graphic and less textual information.

#### Is there any way to choose whether GoogleBot indexes the urls in the old `_escaped_fragment_=` or the new way with JavaScript?

Are there any adaptions I need to make to my existing apps in light of this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Answer: No.

The JavaScript support is not new. They just announced it and have provided a tool in GWT to view how it renders.

They are mainly talking about rendering by executing JavaScript and not about crawling, however it is related.

Google will probably look at the rendered page for links. So what do your links look like? Do they still use the #! ? If so, Google will still follow that link and index via your _escaped_fragment_ URL.

The only real difference is that we can assume Google is getting better at finding those links in JavaScript, so we don't have to provide alternate ways for them to be discovered.

Comment: "fetch as googlebot" did not show JavaScript rendered pages for us yesterday, and it does today. so it means that even if they did show JS before, they've substantially improved its support. How can we verify which pages Google gets?

Comment: All it means is they created a tool to show you something similar to how they parse a page. Google is aware of the bug that means # based urls are not currently supported by their tool.